# How to create doughnut highchart using angular JS

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I want to create a doughnut highchart using angular js.

javascript is-

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: 0,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser<br>shares<br>2015',
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            y: 40
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    distance: -50,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: 'white',
                        textShadow: '0px 1px 2px black'
                    }
                },
                startAngle: -180,
                endAngle: 180,
                center: ['50%', '55%']
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            innerSize: '50%',
            data: [
                ['Firefox',   10.38],
                ['IE',       56.33],
                ['Chrome', 24.03],
                ['Safari',    4.77],
                ['Opera',     0.91],
                {
                    name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
                    y: 0.9,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

html is-

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

and I am including these scripts files -

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

How would I convert the above script in angular js. Can anyone help me on this?
I think some directive function needs to be created.I am new to custom directives in angular, can anybody help how we do this in angular for the doughnut highchart?

Comment: How about using the [highcharts-ng](https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng) ?

Comment: highcharts-ng is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

No need to convert the highcharts in angular as its already exists. No need to inject the dependencies. You can use it directly. Just inject the highcharts
files

```
<script src="script/chart/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="script/chart/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="script/chart/drilldown.js"></script>
<script src="script/chart/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
<script src="script/chart/exporting.js"></script>
```

as per need. and in controller use directly the Highcharts.chart({//code goes here}). Here is the link [for donut highchart](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/3.1.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/3d-pie-donut/)